# Taming Android ListView Height within a TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

n.b.: I was going to post all this XML on Pastebin but I think it's important to have it archived here for posterity, so please pardon the code sample length! Better to have more info than less, right?

Consider the following calculator-ish layout. (I hard-coded the strings just for this post - they are normally resources.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calculator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRowFieldName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewFieldName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Label"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRowDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewDisplay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Value"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param A" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param B" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param C" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param D" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonE"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param E" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonF"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param F" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/calcKeypad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/button7"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="7" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button8" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="8" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button9" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="9" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="4" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button5" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="5" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button6"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="6" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="1" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="2" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button3" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="3" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="C" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button0" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="0" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/buttonDecimal" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="." />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTotal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button android:id="@+id/buttonTotalWeight"
                style="@style/FunctionButton"
                android:text="Function A" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/buttonTotalCost" 
                style="@style/FunctionButton"
                android:text="Function B" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/buttonAbout" 
                style="@style/FunctionButton"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="Function C" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This uses the following styles (essentially factored out of the original XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    </style>  
    <style name="ParameterButton" parent="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0.5</item>
    </style>
    <style name="KeypadButton" parent="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FunctionButton" parent="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0.375</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If you were to drop all of this in to an Android project, you should see three rows of two parameter buttons up top, followed by a numeric keypad below that, with three function buttons to the right of the keypad. Mostly harmless. (Also, it will only ever be used in portrait - so no worries about taking landscape into consideration.)

However ... pay particular attention to the **ListView** within the XML. You won't see it in the visual just yet, since it has `android:visibility="gone"`. The idea is that, at certain times, I will remove that, then set the numeric keypad (the adjacent **TableLayout**) to have `android:visibility="gone"` instead, thus showing the list in its place.

Put another way, the desired effect is to have the list and the numeric keypad occupy exactly the same space, such that I can flip back and forth between the two at will.

The problem I'm having is that the **ListView**, once populated, seems intent on taking up the entire height of the overall table, obliterating the poor parameter buttons and bringing the three function buttons along for the ride.

You can see this by rigging a very basic **ArrayAdapter** (I used `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and `android.R.id.text1`) and tossing a rudimentary `String` array its way. For now, manually move the `gone` assignment from the list over to the adjacent table layout (or do it in code).

Setting a fixed height seems out of the question, since this should be working on a variety of displays. In fact, I even tried what is perhaps a misguided endeavor:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
TableLayout calcKeypad = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.calcKeypad);

list.layout(calcKeypad.getLeft(), calcKeypad.getTop(), calcKeypad.getRight(), calcKeypad.getBottom());
calcKeypad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Nope, that didn't help either.

In keeping with [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), I've even given **ListView** the proper ID since I want to customize its layout. Of course I'm not using a **ListActivity**, so perhaps it doesn't matter in this case. (I'm just using a regular **Activity**. Yes, I tried changing that to **ListActivity** too. No dice.)

Still, I'm totally open to this being pilot error. (In fact, I'm counting on it.) I'm just at the point where it's become head-hitting-the-wall-in-myopia mode. "There's got to be a better way!"

Again, keep in mind I'm trying very hard to keep the layout fluid, so that it works well on a variety of display sizes (not tablets, just handhelds), hence the chosen layout. If there's a better way that accomplishes the same visual, I'm all ears.

Bottom line: How do I make the **ListView** only take up the area occupied by that adjacent calculator keypad (**TableLayout**)?

Clues/answers/guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your layout, but I didn't spend a lot of time trying to sort out the various `layout_weight` and `layout_height` situations that you have. I think you *might* be able to get this to work, but I took a little different approach.

I broke the layout up into a series of rows above the three elements at the bottom. Basically you have:

```
TextView-------------------------------
TextView-------------------------------
LinearLayout---------------------------
LinearLayout---------------------------
LinearLayout---------------------------
---------------------------------------
TableLayout and ListView | LinearLayout
```

I'm not saying this is the most efficient layout, but every layout element has a job, so you might have to go to some lengths to replace them with something more efficient.

In particular, the use of `LinearLayout` for your Parameter buttons and Function buttons makes good use of the `layout_weight` feature. It's not available in other layouts that are not subclasses of `LinearLayout` (you may not be aware that `TableRow` is a subclass of `LinearLayout`, and that's why `layout_weight` works there but not in `RelativeLayout`) and the ability to subdivide available space on a percentage basis seems to be appropriate for those elements.

The TableLayout holding the numeric buttons could probably be replaced, but it's doing a good job of allocating space for the buttons in different sized views, and it is also doing a nice job of spacing the rows to fill the available space. Again, it might be difficult to replace this.

What I did was replace your overall `TableLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` with appropriate alignment attributes. That allows you to put the Function button `LinearLayout` against the right border and have the `ListView` or `TableLayout` consume the remaining space below the Parameter buttons and to the left of the Function buttons. I'm not saying you have to do this, necessarily, but it saves some extra layout elements over your original design and does the job you are looking for.

Here's a workup of what I did. Notice that I added a `layout_height` of `wrap_content` to your ParameterButton style. Also, both the `ListView` and `TableLayout` are visible in this layout. You may want adjust in the layout or in your code.

The style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    </style>  
    <style name="ParameterButton" parent="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0.5</item>
    </style>
    <style name="KeypadButton" parent="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FunctionButton" parent="CalcButton">
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0.375</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calculator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewFieldName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Label"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewDisplay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewFieldName"
            android:text="Value"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Param A" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param B" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param C" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param D" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonE"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param E" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonF"
            style="@style/ParameterButton"
            android:text="Param F" />
    </LinearLayout>



        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_below="@id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayoutTotal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/calcKeypad"
            android:layout_below="@id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/linearLayoutTotal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/button7"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="7" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button8" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="8" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button9" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="9" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="4" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button5" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="5" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button6"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="6" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="1" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="2" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button3" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="3" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="C" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/button0" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="0" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/buttonDecimal" 
                    style="@style/KeypadButton"
                    android:text="." />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/linearLayoutTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonTotalWeight"
            style="@style/FunctionButton"
            android:text="Function A" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonTotalCost" 
            style="@style/FunctionButton"
            android:text="Function B" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonAbout" 
            style="@style/FunctionButton"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Function C" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Oh. My. You did it. This blends the best bits of TableLayout and RelativeLayout. For some reason I could not get that list to behave but, wow, there it is. Thanks tons!

Comment: Awesome answer and appropriately nests the Layouts according to their designed purpose. Also well explained. +1 (+5 if I could)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that layout width is set to be fill parent 
use wrap content instead and assign weight 1 to both table layout and llistview after placing them under horizontal linear layout

Comment: Yep, I tried wrap_content, but I must be doing something wrong because that still didn't work. Hmm. I tried it again. This time, inside tableRow4, I added a horizontal LinearLayout (width/height = wrap_content), and inside THAT I placed listViewSelect, the keypad TableLayout, and linearLayoutTotal. I also changed listViewSelect to use wrap_content for width/height and made sure listViewSelect and the keypad TableLayout had weight of 1. (I also moved visibility="gone" over to the keypad TableLayout.) When I do that, linearLayoutTotal fills the entire screen with the exception of the two labels.

Answer (score 1):

Joe,

There are a number of solutions that can provide the solution that you seek. After looking at your Layout, I am left to wonder why you are using a TableLayout? I mean, at first glance, a calculator is like a Table, kind of. Have you considered other Layout solutions yourself? You certainly mention that others are ok, but the real question is how you have considered them or what you know about them. Because of the lack of information in this regard, I am going to highlight the different kinds of Layouts and their particular strengths. The reason I am addressing it in this way is that most Layout issues result from choosing the wrong layout type.

**FrameLayout**

This Layout is tricky for some. It is great if you have multiple Views that are the same size. The positioning of the immediate children is always the same (top left of the Frame), regardless of size. The weakness of FrameLayout is that you must manually position children if they are going to be on the screen at the same time. Many developers (wrongfully) stick them inside a container in order to keep positioning.

**LinearLayout**

One of the most over-used Layouts. LinearLayouts are particularly awesome if you have similarly sized views that must grow the parent linearly. Many, many novice developers use LinearLayout and `layout_weight` for everything. The issue is that in many cases, things aren't truly growing linearly and `layout_weight` is relatively inefficient, according to Google itself.

**RelativeLayout**

A great layout that offers incredibly flexibility with relative positioning. Positioning is based on previously declared view ids or parent attributes. If your positioning is based on sibling properties, this layout is the best to use. It also does not require `layout_weight`, but allows you to utilize it. The most important thing here is ordering. If your views aren't ordered correctly in your XML then they don't render correctly or error out. Ordering is determined by what views determine your other properties.

**TableLayout**

Layout that provides a grid/cell like structure for your layouts. Its sizing is entirely dependent upon the parent, and positioning is, in most cases, based upon the previous cell. One of the things many devs learn is that it can be troublesome with hidden Views and cells of different sizes. This is best for displaying data or its interfaces.

**Now, for your Solutions**

1. If you are still keen on using the TableLayout, set the visibility of your ListView to `"invisible"` rather than `"gone"`. The difference between these two is subtle but important. `"invisible"` means that it still takes up layout even though it is not visible. `"gone"` means that it loses all of its layout properties and they must be set manually when you show the object.
2. Given your particular requirements, I think a RelativeLayout would be optimal for positioning. It doesn't require you to use the `layout_weight` which optimizes the layout and measure passes. And it allows you to size and position according to how other views and layouts are placed on the screen. You simply have to decide what your anchor views are and start there. Then you can place your ListView with `layout_below`

If you need more information on any of these Layouts, I will gladly provide links for you to the official sources.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Comment: First, what a well-written overview of layouts and rationale - thank you! Now, why would I ever use TableLayout? Good question. I first started with a GridLayout, but that quickly went sour. After that, I tried LinearLayout oh so briefly, read about performance warnings, and quickly moved to RelativeLayout (which, I agree, seems like the wisest choice), but I could never get things to work at multiple resolutions. That's when I thought: "Well, this is table-like, though it isn't data, it's buttons" ... and I ended up with TableLayout. Personally, I see my use of TableLayout as more of a hack.

Comment: As for the ListView, I also tried using `"invisible"` vs. `"gone"` and, at least for me, it made no difference. This could be due to misuse, so I'm going to try it again. I'm also going to give RelativeLayout another shot. As for `"gone"` causing a view to lose all of its layout properties, so far I have not found this to be the case with regard to the buttons.

Comment: As for `"gone"` causing a view to lose all of its layout properties, so far I have not found this to be the case with regard to the buttons. One thing I did not show in this example (in order to simplify it a bit) is that one row of the buttons up top may change from two to three or even one deep (client requirement). Rather than keep removing/adding buttons to the view, I kept all three in there and used `"gone"` at appropriate times on each. When I change them back and forth, they neatly take up the correct amount of space. (Perhaps this is due to other properties that take precedence.)

Comment: OK, now for my response to your solutions! I previously tried using `"invisible"` vs `"gone"`. What happens is rather interesting. To recap, we want the ListView and the numeric keypad TableLayout to share the same space, but only appear one at a time, with no layout side-effects to the broader layout, and to have it all be consistent no matter what the resolution. Here's what happens. ListView: `"gone"` works, `"invisible"` clobbers the layout. TableLayout: `"invisible"` or `"gone"` has the same effect: The ListView expands to the top of the TableView, obliterating all the buttons up top.

Comment: Note that when I say that `"gone"` works for ListView, that's terrific for the TableLayout and the buttons, but not when the shoe's on the other foot and the ListView needs to be seen while the TableLayout is out of sight. That leaves RelativeLayout. Even then, the last time I tried using it, I had the exact same problem with that pesky ListView. It just seems to want to fill all the height that is available to it within any given container, even if at the expense of other things like buttons. This entire layout has to gracefully and consistently fill whatever screen it is displayed on.

Comment: OK. Let me write up the adjusted RelativeLayout for you (as I have done a calculator). The interesting thing about nested Layouts are that they always are tricky the first few COMPLICATED layouts that you do. I frequently use a mix between code-driven and XML-driven layouts. This ultimately means that sometimes your nesting is affecting everything so adding or removing the appropriate layer makes a HUGE difference.

Comment: Would love to see it! I will go look for my other version as a comparison. (Can post to pastebin if that helps.)

Comment: Update: Brian Cooley has weighed in with a blend of table and relative layouts and - whaddaya know - the thing works!